# how is push_back implemented in STL vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I was asked this question in an interview.

The points I answered are like this

1) an index pointing to the current position;

2) resize if neccessary.

Can anybody elaborate more?

Comment: The question was about specific implementation? All implementations are allowed to be different.

Comment: The answer is "that's implementation defined". Seriously, stupid interview questions should be punishable by a severe beating over the head by a cluebat...

Comment: @DevSolar, I think it's programmers who can't write a vector should be punished.  We both have a point (and a bat).

Comment: @DevSolar, why should companies be punished for showing how much they do or do not know about C++ and STL? Seems like that information is good to have.

Comment: Looks like that employer had a lucky escape.

Comment: Unless you presented yourself as having implemented a version of STL, it does seem that this is an odd question.

As phrased, it's a trivia question.

I might instead ask how one might implement it, given the requirements of the standard, and ensure that your remember things like if your size exceeds the capacity.

But it seems odd to me to require and interview subject to know how STL routines are implemented.

Comment: @JohnMcG The question was obviously not asked as phrased, unless the the interviewer was a caveman. I expect that the question (which skydoor is typically incapable of reproducing) was something like - "How might you go about implementing the push_back function of  a vector?" which is entirely reasonable.

Comment: @Neil: Whether your judgment is right or wrong, I don't think this is a place for personal attacks.

Answer (score 22):

An STL `vector` has a [`size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) (current number of stored elements) and a [`capacity`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity) (currently allocated storage space).

- If `size < capacity`, a `push_back` simply puts the new element at the end and increments the `size` by 1.
- If `size == capacity` before the `push_back`, a new, larger array is allocated (twice the size is common, but this is implementation-dependent afaik), all of the current data is copied over (including the new element), and the old allocated space is freed. This may throw an exception if the allocation fails.

The complexity of the operation is *amortized* O(1), which means during a `push_back` that causes a resize, it won't be a constant-time operation (but in general over many operations, it is).

Comment: I want also to comment that the amortized cost O(1) is the case if the new capacity is `k` times bigger than the old one.  It's also of note that, for a given `k`, each element is copied `1/(k-1)` times on average (for `k=2` it's just one additional copy).

Comment: Also, `2` is not the most common factor. Most implementations have shifted to the golden ratio because it plays nicer with memory... this had been discussed here on SO and a comp.lang.c++.moderated thread was referenced.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. Thanks for the info; can you provide links to the discussions you mention?

Answer (score 5):

```
template< typename T >
void std::vector<T>::push_back(const T& obj)
{
    this->insert(this->end(),obj);
}
```

Comment: You mean `void std::vector<T>::push_back` ?

Comment: Perfect response to a bad question.  Technically correct without answering what they *meant* to ask.

Comment: @Graphics: Maybe I'm dense, but I'm not sure what else was expected. I think asked "How is push_back implemented in `std::vector`?" I would have given this answer in the interview.

Comment: @sbi I would assume they're looking for an answer involving memory management (like tzaman's answer).

Comment: @Graphics: I had interviews like that. They asked a question and I pointed out the error in it. Didn't wok out.

Answer (score 3):

That, of course, is inherently implementation defined. Assuming it's a question of how somebody would implement a dynamic array, in general, it'd be something like this:

1. `push_back` checks `capacity()` and ensures it's at least one larger than `size()`.
2. If there is no capacity for the new element, the vector reallocates it's entire underlying storage, copying over the contents of the old storage to the new storage. The old storage is deallocated.
3. The new element is copied to the end of the dynamic array.

Some STL implementations will elide some of the copies by using swaps (i.e. for containers of containers), but for the most part that's exactly how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly what they were looking for is that `push_back` makes a copy of the object being pushed onto the `vector` (using its copy constructor).

With regard to resizing: The standard says `a.push_back(x)` is equivalent to `a.insert(a.end(),x)`. The definition of `insert` says, in part: “Causes reallocation if the new size is greater than the old capacity.”

The standard says *what* the functions are supposed to do. But how they’re implemented is, in most cases, implementation-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
void push_back(T const& param)
{
  vector temp(rbegin(), rend());
  temp.push_front(param);
  *this = vector(temp.rbegin(), temp.rend());
}
```

Comment: This seems like a fairly expensive implementation. You first copy the contents of the vector in reverse, which requires allocation + O(n) iteration to copy of each element in the vector. Then you push the parameter to the *beginning* of the temporary vector, which requires yet another allocation and O(n) accompanying element copy operations.  Then you create another copy of the temporary (allocation + O(n) reverse iteration/element copies) that is copy assigned to the vector being operated on.  That assignment will result in deallocation + O(n) element destruction operations.  Kinda slow. :)

Comment: The greatest implementation I know so far

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some comments, I am completely revising a very incorrect original answer.

[According to the STL spec](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/), your answer was correct.  The vector is implemented as a dynamically resized array:

> Vector containers are implemented as dynamic arrays; Just as regular arrays, vector containers have their elements stored in contiguous storage locations, which means that their elements can be accessed not only using iterators but also using offsets on regular pointers to elements.
>   
>   But unlike regular arrays, storage in vectors is handled automatically, allowing it to be expanded and contracted as needed.

Comment: No. Absolutely not. A vector is a dynamic array -- the standard requires that the underlying storage be the exact same as a builtin array. The standard requires only O(1) *amortized* time. Therefore, it need only be O(1) in the average case.

Comment: The underlying buffer of a vector must be contiguous, meaning it cannot be a linked list.  The push_back() method can still run in constant time (on average) if resizing doesn't occur during each call.  This typically requires that the buffer increase in size by some factor (e.g. double in size whenever the vector is full).

Answer (score 0):

`vector` doesn't use a linked list. It uses continuous memory.

If there is not enough reserved space `push_back` allocates a new chunk of memory *twice* as large as the original `vector`. By doing that the amortized runtime is O(1).

Comment: ...a new chunk that's larger than the old by some constant factor anyway -- but the factor is typically around 1.5 rather than 2.

Comment: @Jerry, strange.  For a factor of 1.5 two copies for each elements on average are needed, whereas for the factor of 2 it's just 1 copy.

Comment: @Pavel: Andrew Koenig wrote an article years ago about one reason to favor a smaller factor. With a factor of two, the sum of chunks you've discarded will always be smaller than your next larger allocation, so you never get to reuse them for the same container. As long as the factor is <=the golden mean, they'll eventually add up to a large enough chunk to re-use for the next larger allocation.

Comment: @Coffin, this is the case only if the underlying memory manager allocates the chunks thriftily.  However, the manager may stick to 2^n chunks which renders the 1.5-scheme useless.

Answer (score 0):

How much detail did the interviewer want?  For example, was he looking for you to drill down into the lower level details?

Besides the usual resize-as-needed to retain the O(1) on average semantics, some things to consider include but are not limited to:

- **Exception safety**: Does the implementation provide a guarantee that state of the vector will not be modified if an exception is thrown when appending the new element (e.g. rollback semantics)?  For example, an exception could be thrown during allocation, copying, insertion, etc.
- **Proper use of allocator**: Does the implementation correctly use the `vector`'s allocator instead of plain old `new` based allocator (both may or may not be the same)?  Ideally, this will be handled transparently by the `vector`'s resizing code, implementations could certainly differ, however.

Answer (score 0):

If size < capasity, then everything seems to be ok, you just insert en element in vector, the complexity accures when size == capasity.

It is easy to explaint on words that you have to allocate a new array twice larger then existing one and copy all those elements in new alocated memory and after delete the old one and insert the new element in new array. But here are some key moments which I consider your interviewer expects you to mention.

1. The elements in std::vector are not kept in one array, so the data member of std::vector[1000] is not a int* of lenght 1000. The elements are kept in blocks of memory, thus you must consider it when copying.
2. Secondly, the standard stl vector requires "give me a copyable object and I can insert it", which means that requierment on std::vector is that sometype only has to have a copy_constructer (not operator = ). So when you are alocating a new memory of type sometype, you must consider that sometyme may not have a default copy constructer. In common implementations, this is done by placement new operator to avoid the call of copy constructors.

Comment: Old question, but either I missunderstand 1) or it is plain wrong. std::vector gurantees that all its elements are stored consecutively in memory (aka in a single array).